# Time Difference between 2 datetime fileds, only working hours

Tags: vb.net, date-difference

I have 2 fields datetime (`TaskStartDate` and `TaskEndDate`). I created another field and called it `Duration`.

I need to update `Duration` to reflect how many business hours and minutes between the 2 fields (`TaskStartDate` and `TaskEndDate`) noting that we work only 8 hours a day.

Example:

```
TaskStartDate 2014-01-01 07:30
TaskEndDate   2014-01-03 15:30       Duration should read 24 Hours not 72hours
```

Comment: What language are you using or intend to use?  What have you tried?

Comment: And where are you going to get your working hours definitions from? Ie weekends, holidays and 'business hours'